# Query for equal decimals in row

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
 name,     type,  q1,      q2,    x,     p  
 'BW',     'x', '2.00', '90.00', NULL, '5.00'
 'Bremen', 'x', '3.00', '90.00', NULL, '4.00'
 'Bayern', 'x', '3.00', '90.00', NULL, '6.00'
 'Hessen', 'x', '3.00', '95.00', NULL, '7.00'
 'RP',     'x', '3.00', '95.00', NULL, '9.00'
```

I want to select those rows that have equal q1 AND q2 values. That is, I need three results (perhaps then 3 queries):

Result 1:

```
 name,     type,  q1,      q2,    x,     p  
 'Bremen', 'x', '3.00', '90.00', NULL, '4.00'
 'Bayern', 'x', '3.00', '90.00', NULL, '6.00'
```

Result 2:

```
 name,     type,  q1,      q2,    x,     p  
 'BW',     'x', '2.00', '90.00', NULL, '5.00'
```

Result 3:

```
 name,     type,  q1,      q2,    x,     p  
 'Hessen', 'x', '3.00', '95.00', NULL, '7.00'
 'RP',     'x', '3.00', '95.00', NULL, '9.00'
```

Can someone give me a hint how to get the queries? Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to order the query by the q1 and q2 values:

```
select t.*
from t
order by q1, q2;
```

This will return rows in order, so rows with the same values are next to each other.

Comment: This is actually about as correct as can be. OP wants 1+ rows per "group", so essentially it's a `select *` **ANYWAYS**. If it had been a n+-type group,t hen this would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE q1 = q2
```

You have to replace `[TABLE]` with your table name

I have no clue what you want with the other 3 queries